# Is it possible to reduce the complexity of radix-2 FFT if the input vector contains identical elements?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft

my question is about reducing the complexity of radix-2 FFT when the input vector has a specific structure.

For an input vector of **x** with *N* elements, the complexity is given by **O**(*N* log2 *N*).

My input vector **y** with *N* elements has the structure of:
**y** = [**x1** **x2**]T

where,

**x1** = **x2**

and **x1** and **x2** vectors have *N*/2 elements. Is it possible to reduce the complexity of radix-2 FFT for this **y** vector? I think it is possible to not use one of the *N*/2 DFT blocks of the FFT algorithm in this case. Can anyone show me what is the complexity for this vector? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if

$$\text{FFT}\{[a, b, c, d]\} = [p, q, r, s]$$

then

$$\text{FFT}\{[a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d]\} = [p, 0, q, 0, r, 0, s, 0]$$

or 
$$=[2p, 0, 2q, 0, 2r, 0, 2s, 0]\text,$$

depending on normalization.

Edit:
Using this property, we can make FFT nearly 2x faster on this specialized data. But the complexity is still $O(n \log n)$. I mean, big O notation doesn't count constant factor.

Comment: Thank you. Assuming no normalization, i.e., DFT{x}=sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i e^{..}, it is known that FFT implementation leads to a complexity of N log_2 N. If we have a structured vector as above, i.e., x=[x_0,x_0,x_1,x_1,...,x_N/2,x_N/2], then can we say that the FFT complexity can be reduced to (N/2) log_2(N/2)? I appreciate your response in advance.

Comment: @MustafaAnılReşat So what is actually your question? Something like [a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d] or [a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d] ?

Comment: Sorry for previous mistake. I should have written it as a vector structure of [a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d]. Let me repeat the question again correctly. Assuming no normalization, i.e., DFT{x}=sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i e^{..}, it is known that FFT implementation leads to a complexity of N log_2 N. If we have a structured vector as  x=[x_0,x_1,...,x_N/2,x_0,x_1,...,x_N/2],                                                              then can we say that the FFT complexity can be reduced to (N/2) log_2(N/2)? I appreciate your response in advance.

Comment: @MustafaAnılReşat I edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: @mfcc64 I think if we ignored the multiplication which results 0 values, the complexity will be reduced up to half, right?